# For an irrep $E$ of $SO(3)$, why is $E^{SO(2)}$ one-dimensional?

Tags: representation-theory

Consider an irreducible representation $E$ of $SO(3)$ and consider $SO(2)$ as a subgroup of $SO(3)$ in the natural way.

In http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2016-17/2term/ma145b/notes/RepCptGroups.pdf, Alexander Yom Din says (in page 26) that $E^{SO(2)}$ is one-dimensional. In his notes it appears to be a very simple result but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the Section 7.10 of the notes, there is one irreducible representation $E_d$ of $SO(3)$ for each *odd* dimension $d+1$ (there appears to be a typo in the notes here: the dimension should be $d+1$, not $d$, to be consistent with previous conventions). These irreducible representations are described at the end of section 6.1: they are spanned by basis vectors $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_d$ on which $\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix}\in SU(2)$ (or equivalently $\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\theta) & -\sin(2\theta) & 0\\ \sin(2\theta) & \cos(2\theta) &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\in SO(3)$) acts by multiplication by $v_k\mapsto e^{i(d-2k)\theta}v_k = e^{i(\frac{d}{2}-k)2\theta}v_k$. The $SO(2)$-invariant subspace of this space is spanned by $v_{d/2}$, and so is 1-dimensional.